# Como usar uma função dentro de outra função em python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu queria pegar o resultado do input da função nome e usar dentro da função intro, porém da forma que estou tentando, obtenho apenas um erro.

código:

```
def nome():
    name = str(input('Poderia nos dizer seu nome? '))
    return name

def intro():
    nome()
    print('Olá {}, seja bem vindo!'.format(name))


intro()
```

E este é o erro que obtive como resultado:

[image: Erro ao executar o código descrito]

sou iniciante na área,agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se na função `nome()` você **retorna** o valor lido, você precisará armazenar esse valor em uma variável. A variável `name` que você definiu dentro de `nome()` não existe dentro de `intro()`. São escopos diferentes.

```
def nome():
    name = input('Poderia nos dizer seu nome? ')
    return name

def intro():
    name = nome()
    print('Olá {}, seja bem vindo!'.format(name))


intro()
```

Perceba que removi o `str()` do `input` também, pois isso é redundante; o retorno do `input` sempre será uma *string*.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou como eu queria. No momento tenho que esperar para aceitar a resposta, mas assim que possível o farei.

Answer (score 1):

Para que seu codigo funcione faça assim:

```
def nome():
    name = input('Poderia nos dizer seu nome? ')
    return name

def intro(name):
    print('Olá {}, seja bem vindo!'.format(name))

name = nome()
intro(name)
```

Observe que a variavel name esta sendo passada como um parametro para a fução intro()

Também, no python é permitido a criação de funções aninhadas e o seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
def intro():
    name = nome()
    print('Olá {}, seja bem vindo!'.format(name))

    def nome():
        name = input('Poderia nos dizer seu nome? ')
        return name

# aqui a chamada da função intro
intro()
```

E seja feliz...

Comment: Eu ia fazer outra pergunta, pq da forma que coloquei o código, sempre que eu quisesse a função nome dentro de outra função, ficaria pedindo para digitar o nome novamente, da forma que você fez o código funciona. Muito obrigado! pena eu só poder aceitar uma das respostas.